# visualizar servicios en forma de columnas php, html y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Espero puedan ayudarme tengo una pequeña pagina en donde estoy visualizando unos servicios que ya tengo registrados en una base de datos la cual mando a llamar para que se visualicen los servicios en esa parte de la pagina, los servicios se muestran sin problema cadaservicio tiene un titulo y una foto que esta en la base de datos, la cuestion es que los servicios se visualizan en modo lista y estoy trabajando para que se miren en columnas quisiera que cuando se vallana agregando servicios se visualicen en tres columnas por ejemplo que si tengo 9 servicios se vean tres en cada columna si son menos solo ocupen el espacio que tengan talvez tres en la primera columna y dos en la siguiente y la ultima vacia,, si son mas de 9 servicios que solo se muestren los ultimos nueve que se agregaron para que siempre muestre 9

la idea es que se vea asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo con el que muestro los servicios es este

```html
<?php include("admin/conexion.php");
    ?>
    <?php
                                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM service ORDER BY id DESC";
                                                $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
                                                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                                            ?>
              
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="position-relative">
                       
               
                            <div class="position-relative bg-light rounded-bottom text-center p-4">
                                <h2><strong><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></strong></h2>
                               
                                                 <div class="position-relative h-100">  
                                     <img width="300" height="200"  src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['imagen']); ?>"/>
                           
                           
                     </div>
                                       
                            </div>
</div>  
                         </div>           
                   
                <?php } ?>
```

Con este codigo los servicios se miran asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les leo, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Esto se llama diseño responsivo o [responsive web design](https://www.google.com/search?q=responsive+web+design) y requiere un relativo manejo de CSS, JS y HTML. ¿Estás usando Bootstrap, Foundation o similares?, si es así, es pan comido. Si no conoces mucho de CSS y frontend, recomiendo [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) para salir de ese problema facilmente.

Comment: si uso  Bootstrap como haria para dar esa forma a los registros y que se acomoden en columnas no en filas

Comment: usa el sistema de columnas o grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/

Comment: si entiendo pero al usarlo solo me sigue generando una lista o una columna y lo que estoy buscando es que cuando ingrese mas servicios se agregen en automatico en la primera columna 3 por ejemplo y luego se vallan corriendo a la segunda columna y es hay donde no :S me sale